# removing words that appear more than x% in a corpus Python

Tags: python, for-loop, text-processing

I am dealing with a large corpus in the form of a list of tokens/words. The corpus contains ~1900,000 words, I have run a code to get the most frequent words and now the corpus has 140,000 word.

I would like to remove the words that appear more than 95% of the document and less than 5%

sample of the corpus

```
['problems', 'guess', 'sleep', 'holy']
```

First I found the most frequent words

```
from nltk.probability import FreqDist

corpus_frequency = FreqDist(corpus)

corpus_commom=corpus_frequency.most_common()
```

Then, I applied this for loop to find the list of words that appear more than 95%

```
most_frequent=[mytuple for mytuple in corpus_commom if mytuple[1]<len(corpus*95)/100]
```

But this code takes very long time to run, and it does not return any output.

I also tried to follow some answers I found and apply CountVectorizer but I get an error message

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer(min_df=0.05, max_df=0.95, lowercase=True) 
X = cv.fit_transform(corpus)
```

The error message

```
ValueError: After pruning, no terms remain. Try a lower min_df or a higher max_df.
```

**Update**

The CountVectorizer works if I do this

```
cv = CountVectorizer(corpus,max_df=0.95)
count_vector=cv.fit_transform(corpus)
```

But it returns a list of numbers. I would like the output to be my corpus(list of words) filtered.

Can anyone give me a tip on how to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: This doesn't look right: `if mytuple[1]<len(corpus*95)/100`. It should probably be: `if mytuple[1]<len(corpus)*0.95`

Comment: Thank you for your note. It just changes the number to the closest value.

Comment: Your call to CountVectorizer looks fine so something is wrong with your corpus. You could try making a small corpus of 10 documents and making sure it works. Also, to confirm your corpus looks ok, what is the output of `print(corpus[0])`?

Comment: @polm23 please find the update I added to the topic

Comment: @leena: You don't seem to get the point. Your line `len(corpus*95)/100` multiplies your corpus 95 times; it literally has 95 copies of your corpus. That is the bug in your code. Move the 95 outside of `len(corpus)`.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 the code runs, but then the output I get is the same length as my original corpus.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that computes the frequency fraction of each token in a list. You can use the fraction to perform your filtering.

```py
import nltk

def get_frac_dist(token_list):
    '''
    Computes frequency count and fraction of individual words in a list.

    Parameters
    ----------
    token_list : list
        List of all (non-unique) tokens from some corpus

    Returns
    -------
    dict
        Dictionary of { token, (count, fraction) } pairs.
    '''

    token_list = nltk.word_tokenize(content)
    total_token_count = len(token_list)

    freq_dict = nltk.FreqDist(token_list)

    frac_dict = {}
    for token, count in freq_dict.items():
        frac_dict[token] = (count, count / total_token_count)

    return frac_dict
```

Here's how you can use it:

1. Open a file, tokenize it with `nltk.word_tokenize()`, and pass the token list into `get_frac_dist()`.

```py
with open('speech.txt') as f:
    content = f.read()

token_list = nltk.word_tokenize(content)
frac_dist = get_frac_dist(token_list)
```

2. The `get_frac_dist()` returns a dictionary. The key is a token, and the value is a tuple containing (frequency count, frequency fraction). Let's take a look at the first 10 items in the dictionary.

```py
i = 0
for k, v in frac_dist.items():

    i += 1
    if i > 10:
        break

    token = k
    count = v[0]
    frac = v[1]
    print('%-20s: %5d, %0.5f' % (token, count, frac))
```

prints out:

```
President           :     2, 0.00081
Pitzer              :     1, 0.00040
,                   :   162, 0.06535
Mr.                 :     3, 0.00121
Vice                :     1, 0.00040
Governor            :     1, 0.00040
Congressman         :     2, 0.00081
Thomas              :     1, 0.00040
Senator             :     1, 0.00040
Wiley               :     1, 0.00040
```

3. Now, if you want to get the words with the fraction greater than or less than some value, run a loop or a list comprehension using `<` or `>` appropriately.

```py
l = [ (k, v[0], v[1]) for k, v in frac_dist.items() if v[1] > 0.04 ]
print(l)
```

prints out:

```
[(',', 162, 0.0653489310205728), ('and', 104, 0.04195240016135539), ('the', 115, 0.0463896732553449)]
```

Be aware that your desire to get the words that occur more than 95% of the time may not return any valid answer. You should plot out the distribution of words and see what their counts are.

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, you have no terms remain after transformation.
That is, every word appears more than 95% or less then 5%. For example:

```
corpus = ['This is a good sentence',
          'This is a good sentence',
          'This is a good sentence',
          'This is a good sentence',
          'This is a good sentence']
cv = CountVectorizer(min_df=0.05, max_df=0.95) 
X = cv.fit_transform(corpus)
```

will raise the same error. But this does not make sense when your corpus has 1900,000 words. Perhaps you can check whether your corpus is a valid argument of `CountVectorizer`. See more detail in https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html .

Comment: Thank you Jason. I read that document before posting my question but I still can't make my code work.

Comment: What is your corpus? Is it a list of string? Can you show the first few lines of your corpus?

Comment: A sample of my corpus is in the topic. It is a list of words.

Comment: I managed to make the countVectorizer work by doing this edit: `#ignore the word that appear more than 95% in the document 
cv = CountVectorizer(corpus,max_df=0.95)
count_vector=cv.fit_transform(corpus)` But it returns number, and I want my corpus filtered. I would like the list of words returned without the words that appeared more than 95%